# Update and Insert cases in postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `tab` with columns:

```
userid, usercode, value
```

I'm writing a `plpgsql` function that update/insert the table.
In case userid & usercode exists I need to update value
In case they don't I need to insert the new value

for example if table data is:

```
userid, usercode, value
  5       10        20 
  3       8         10
```

for function call:

```
addvalue(5, 10 , 40)
addvalue(1, 12 , 40.5)
```

The new data will be:

```
userid, usercode, value
  5       10        60 
  3       8         10
  1       12        40.5
```

This is My function body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addvalue(xuserid integer, xusercode Integer,xvalue Numeric)
RETURNS integer AS

$BODY$ 
begin

     insert into tab(userid,usercode,value) values(xuserid ,xusercode,xvalue);
     return 1
end;                
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

What is the best way to find out if I need to do `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statments?

Should I do `UPDATE` and check if it returns 0  ( 0 rows updated) and in that case do `INSERT`? Or should I query `tab` table to see if `userid = xuserid and usercode = xusercode`?

Comment: You might be inserted in this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql.  Or upgrade to postgres 9.5 and use `upsert`.

Comment: I'm on postgresql version 9.0 and can't upgrade further... not at this point anyway.

Comment: @quack - From Gordon's coment you ***could*** have searched the web for any of the many ways to do an `UPSERT` in PostgreSQL 9.0...  http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/upsert/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
 IF xuserid not in (select distinct userid from tab) THEN
 insert into tab(userid,usercode,value) values(xuserid ,xusercode,xvalue);
 ELSE
 update tab
 set value = value + xvalue 
 where userid = xuserid and usercode = xusercode
 END IF;
 -- return 1
end;
```

Is this what you are trying to do?